# Round corners in HTML5 Notification image

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to display corners rounded image in HTML5 notification?

I'm talking about this HTML5 API:

```
new Notification(title, { icon: imageURL });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont't think there is an option the display the Icon with rounded corners.

But a solution could be to make the Image have rounded corners by creating a new Picture with HTMLCanvas:

- Create an canvas-element with the images width and height
- Draw the image on a canvas-element `context.drawImage(img,x,y);`
- Draw rouned corners or Cut with clip-path
- Save the Pictures to use it for the Notification `var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();`

**Edit:** Here is the complete Specification of 'Web Notifications': https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/notifications/raw-file/tip/Overview.html
 - you can only define an image / icon, no style attributes, so yes you will have modify the image yourself